# prolog, test(X, Y, Z) :- Y is X + Z

Tags: prolog, clpfd

How to get Y and Z in prolog, when I only know X?

For example:

```
test(X, Y, Z) :- X is Y + Z.
```

but error:

```
?- test(2, Y, Z).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because you can choose `Y` to be anything you want and them compute `Z` or vice versa.

Although if you know that `Y` and `Z` are from some limited set (e.g. positive integers less than 5), you can do something like:

```
valid_number(1).
valid_number(2).
valid_number(3).
valid_number(4).

test(X, Y, Z) :- valid_number(Y), valid_number(Z), X is Y + Z.
```

Comment: These set constraints can also be achieved with `between/3`.

Comment: Yes. I found this 

between(I,J,J):-J>=I.
between(I,J,K):-J>I, J1 is J - 1, between(I,J1,K). 

?- between(1, 4, X).
X = 4 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 1 ;
false.
 
It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass them as arguments. Prolog arithmetic (`is/2`) is not a magic wand, its right argument must be fully instantiated (no variables) before it can be evaluated.

If you want the predicate to work in several "directions", with multiple combinations of ground terms and variables, you'll want to use Constraint Logic Programming, but that's a rather advanced area of logic programming. In CLP on finite domains, you can say

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).  % this differs between implementations
test(X,Y,Z) :- X #= Y + Z.
```

Comment: I second larsmans' constraint suggestion and find that is much easier to understand for beginners than low-level moded arithmetic. In my opinion, is/2 should be eliminated from introductory courses because it is too hard to understand for beginners.